# Stop button color change on Mouseover

Tags: wpf, button, user-interface

ok..this is very strange....i have defined a button, actually 5 buttons and each have a different color but on mouse over, they just change the color to that icy blue color....i tried to override that by using the below code :

```
        <Button Name="btn1" Content="Button" Width="65" Height="45" Background="Green" Margin="1,1,0,1" FontWeight="Bold">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Yellow" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <Button.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
            </Button.LayoutTransform>
        </Button>
```

but it still does not work...what i want is that it should maintain the background color it has been given(different for each button), so the question is : do i have to define it again and again for each button (the trigger did not work, color becomes ice blue) OR can i define it in the resource file with a generic value that it either stops the color change or just sets background to existing property
EDIT : Just to be clear, i want the button to stop changing its color on mouseover and just retain whatever color i have assigned it.....

Comment: Are you able to stop it from turning the "ice blue", or is that your question?

Comment: no....i'm not able to stop it....yes that is my question that i do not want it to turn ice blue but retain whatever color i assigned it

Comment: Then I think your question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224439/how-do-you-disable-mouseover-effects-on-a-button-in-wpf

Comment: i have been through that question and it did not work for me....it sets a single color in the setter which will be applied to all buttons irrespective of their backgroundcolor....i just don't want the color to change....thats the difference

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the "ice blue" from, however is the button Focused when it changes color? There's a chance its pulling the color from the [SystemColors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/11/30/systemcolors-reference.aspx), in which case you could try overwriting the `SystemColor` for your buttons (maybe Transparent?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments and the SO post I linked: that article applied the style to anything of type `Button`, that's why it applies to all buttons (which is not necessarily a bad thing).  But the salient point to take away from that article is that what you need to modify is the `ControlTemplate`.

So you would want to do something like this:

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" Background="{TemplateBinding Property=Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This isn't perfect, because it loses all of it's interactivity (ie. you can't tell you've pushed it, hovered over it or anything).  But it gives you a good starting point.

One of the key points here is that the `Background` property of the `Border` is bound to the `TemplateParent Property=Background`, that means it's going to read the background property of the button the that it is templating and use it's background color.  This makes it easier for you to use a single style to cover all 5 of your buttons.  You could (and may want to) do similar things with the `BorderBrush` property.

Also notice my style has a `x:Key` value, so in order to use this, you would do:

```
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="Button" Width="65" Height="45" Background="Green" Margin="1,1,0,1" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}">
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270"/>
        </Button.LayoutTransform>
    </Button>
```

You can remove the `x:Key` attribute and the style will indeed apply to all buttons inside of whichever container you declare the resource.

Comment: really good...this does work as i want, just few clarifications before i mark it as answer...why do i have to use border for the background (contentpresenter does not have that property....i checked) ??....also you said, it loses all of it's interactivity but i checked by clicking the button and its click event fired....so what exactly are we talking about ??

Comment: `ContentPresenter` is basically a placeholder control, so it doesn't have a lot of properties.  You don't **have to** use a border, you could use some other container that will give you the ability to specify a background color, its just that `Border` is usually desirable because it gives you the border and the border corners that you usually want.  As far as the "interactivity", usually a button will have some sort of mouse over behavior, like a slightly different color, or the border highlights, or something just so you have some visual cue that the button is active.  Does that help?