# remove blue highlight on buttons wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a WPF project. While running the application, as I take my cursor to a button, it gets highlighted by blue color filled inside it.

Now, I want to remove this highlight...
How do I do so?

[image]

Comment: Link isn't working for me.

Comment: Do you want to prevent button from changing mouse-over color? Then simply remove trigger from button style what does that. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20073418/1997232).

Answer (score 1):

The link isn't working for me, so I can't see exactly what you are getting at, but I assume that you're trying to change that default blue-ish gradient. You need to override the template for the button in a style, and then you can customize it to look however you want. You can't just set the background color or use triggers to change it without overriding the template, because the default template has some extra stuff in it to show that gradient effect.

Here is an example of a button I have used before that is fairly straightforward. This example uses a trigger to change the foreground color of the button when it is pressed, but will never change the background color.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushBtnText}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BrushBorderLight}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                 <Border Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                         BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                         BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                         Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                     <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                 </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushBtnText}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Also, if you're interested, here is what the button's default template is:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Themes:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I moved the image in to the question, want to look at it and re-review your answer?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Thanks for the image. Answer is now updated.

Comment: This didn't help me.... It hides the foreground completely with the contents. I wanted to hide the foreground background only.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the thing where I was going wrong. Whenever my pointer goes to a button, does not change the background of the button or even the foreground of the button, but it changes the background of the border.

So, while overwriting the button style, actually the border of the background has to be overwritten and not the button foreground or the background.

Here is the answer to this question : [How to Disable MouseOver Effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224439/how-do-you-disable-mouseover-effects-on-a-button-in-wpf)