# How to remove ListViewItem on hover highlight?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a buttons in process flow shape, which looks nice but on hover the ugly blue highlights appear underneath. How can I remove it?

Button 2 is highlighted:

[image]

Resource Dictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleMainRed" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#37474f"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Data="F1 M 0.78429,0.50002L 128.79,0.50002L 161.069,32.7785L 129.055,64.7919L 0.500001,64.7919L 32.5214,32.7705L 0.516563,0.765584" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Test"  
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    <Rectangle Name="Led" Width="50" Height="4" Fill="#d50000" Margin="0,40,0,0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#263238"></Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Led" Property="Fill" Value="#f44336"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

View:

```
<views:BaseView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FlowStageTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="ProcessStageButton" 
                    Tag="{Binding ID}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OnButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TurulStageButton}"
                    Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}"
                    Width="160" Height="65" Margin="0,0,-24,0" >
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</views:BaseView.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FlowStagesMainMenu}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlowStageTemplate}" 
              Height="67" BorderThickness="0" Background="#263238" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundHover" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Transparent" />
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

I have tried to hide it by the below, but no change:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundHover" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Transparent" />
```

Comment: Strange, I tried to reproduce and it looks well. I only replaced in your `FlowStageTemplate` code one line: ` Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}"` I replaced with ` Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}"`. No highliht on hover, but I got blue highlight on right click. Seems like you didn't override default selection style.

Comment: I added `<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>` in a `ListViewItem` style, it fixed this behaviour

Comment: What did you replace it for in the first comment? You placed twice: Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}"

Comment: ah sorry wrong copy-paste. it should be `Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleMainRed}"`

Comment: it doesn't work for me, still see the blue highlight on the background

Comment: I also placed `ButtonStyleMainRed` right before `FlowStageTemplate`. That's weird.

Comment: ButtonStyleMainRed is in ResourceDictionary and FlowStagesTemplate is on the View so cant really rearrange it. Could you send me your sample project? maybe that give me an idea what is wrong

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Ciwt/T7rwRbefE

Comment: can you please clarify how exactly the code you posted arranged in files?

Comment: I moved `ButtonStyleMainRed ` to a separate file, included it with ` <Window.Resources><ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/> </Window.Resources>` and moved `FlowStageTemplate` to `StackPanel.Resources`. Still works fine.

Comment: Your example have exactly the same issue. Would that be Win 10?

Comment: So I'm assuming this is a metro style issue. I need this to work on all Windows exactly the same

Comment: Sorry I have no Win10 machine, can't help you here. Good luck anyway. At least you know where to dig now.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: You'll just need to edit a listviewitem template to fit your needs. If you do that while you're in there you can do the stuff you're doing in your itemcontainerstyle directly to it and get rid of that part.

Comment: this is what I don't understand how to do it

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162264/remove-blue-highlight-on-buttons-wpf

Comment: That is not the same, there is about button, here is more about the ListViewItem